# Method not found even though its present in source code

Tags: java, spring, caching, guava

I am using guava 18.

```
group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0'
```

I am using loadingCache:

```
CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .expireAfterWrite(EXPIRE_PRODUCT_AFTER_1_DAY, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                    .refreshAfterWrite(REFRESH_PRODUCT_AFTER_5_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build(new CacheLoader<String, OptionMap>() {
                               @Override
                               public OptionMap load(String productId) throws Exception {
                                   return loadCache(productId);
                               }
                           }
                    );
```

While compiling I am getting:

```
error: cannot find symbol
                    .refreshAfterWrite(REFRESH_PRODUCT_AFTER_5_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    ^
  symbol:   method refreshAfterWrite(Integer,TimeUnit)
  location: class CacheBuilder<Object,Object>
```

Dependency Insight
     gradle -q dependencyInsight --configuration runtime --dependency guava

```
com.google.guava:guava:18.0
```

I am using intellij and its not showing any error while working

Comment: Out of interest, if you specify `REFRESH_PRODUCT_AFTER_5_SECONDS.intValue()` does that help? I don't think it *should*, but...

Comment: What is `REFRESH_PRODUCT_AFTER_5_SECONDS`? It looks like it's an `Integer`, but if it were, the compiler would be able to resolve it against `refreshAfterWrite(long,TimeUnit)` (http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#refreshAfterWrite(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) since it would unbox the `Integer` and the promote it to a `long`.

Comment: currently  REFRESH_PRODUCT_AFTER_5_SECONDS is Integer.Changing it to long also gives error : method refreshAfterWrite(long,TimeUnit)